# How to make an M x 1 cellarray of 1 x N cellarrays from an m x n cellarray?

Tags: matlab

I have an *M* × *N* cell array `A` that I would like to turn into an *M* × 1 cell array `B` whose entries are 1 × *N* cell arrays.

The purpose of this manipulation is so that I can run the command

```
>> cellfun(@(x) str2num(x, ':'), B, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

If I try to do the same directly on `A` I get the error

```
Error using strjoin (line 53)
First input must be a 1xN cell array of strings.
```

Comment: As far as I know, `str2num` accepts only one parameter, and you're passing two. This should trigger an error anyway. What is stored in your cells and what exactly do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`num2cell()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html). Even though the name alludes to numeric arrays, the function is not restricted to numeric inputs (as the help points out).

```
M = 5;
N = 15;
c = cell(M,N);

num2cell(c,2)
ans = 
    {1x15 cell}
    {1x15 cell}
    {1x15 cell}
    {1x15 cell}
    {1x15 cell}
```